# How do I get the missile upgrade blocked by a fan in Area 1?

Tags: metroid-samus-returns

Near the top of Area 1, there is an area on the ceiling accessible using the spider Spider Ball with a missile upgrade behind a wall. The upgrade near a fan that sucks up bombs, preventing me from breaking the wall. How do I get this missile upgrade?

[image: Missile upgrade]

[image: Map location]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [IGN](https://www.ign.com/wikis/metroid-samus-returns/Missile_Expansion_Locations):

> In the big and open room, use the Spider Ball to reach the ceiling. To the left of the Missile Recharge Station is a weak weak[sic]. Break through with a bomb, the enemies with bombs too. There is a weak wall below the expansion but the vent sucks away your bombs. Destroy the two blocks under the vent, then stand up and shoot a missile at the weak spot.

[image: Screenshot]